# Partitions with at most k parts, each of at most l

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

I'm taking a course on Analytics Combinatorics (based on Flajolet's and Sedwick's book), and i'm trying to solve note I.16 of the book, that is, verify:

$$ P^{(\leq l, \{1,\ldots,k\})}(z) = \frac{(1-z)\ldots(1-z^{k+l})}{((1-z)\ldots(1-z^{k}))\cdot((1-z)\ldots(1-z^{l}))} $$
Where the left hand means the generating function of the class of partitions with at most k parts, each $ \leq l $
Truth is I already tried by multiple ways, but with no success:

First, looking at the formula I guessed that:
$$ P^{(\leq l, \{1,\ldots,k\})} \times P^{(\{1,\ldots,k +l\})} \tilde = P^{(<l)} \times P^{(\{1,\ldots,k\})} $$ but i couldn't understand why.

Secondly, using the same reasoning as to find that p(k,l,n) = p(l,k-1,n) + p(l-1,k,n -k), I thought that:

$$ P^{(\leq l, \{1,\ldots,k\})}  \tilde = P^{(\leq l, \{1,\ldots,k-1\})} +\mathcal Z^k \times P^{(\leq l - 1, \{1,\ldots,k\})}  $$

but i could't solve the recurrence.

and so on...

As you can see, I'm quite confused... can someone give a tip that put me in my way? 
thank you in advanced!

Comment: I would quite like to answer but fear it would be a pale imitation of [this](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kNgLCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&dq=counting+with+symmetric+functions&source=bl&ots=TTMMCHFzsS&sig=PNFBNDppCazC1xNdSrm17hihc-w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwm6WynarTAhVMDcAKHSNfAoEQ6AEIXjAM#v=onepage&q=counting%20with%20symmetric%20functions&f=false) fabulous book. You want theorem $1.9$ on page $10$ but I would read pages $1$ to $10$ too if I were you as they lead nicely up to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Let $p(l,k,n)$ denote the number of partitions of $n$ into at most $k$ parts each $\leq l$. Observe that 
>   \begin{align*}
> p(l,k,n)&=0\qquad\qquad\text{if } n>kl\\
> p(l,k,kl)&=1
> \end{align*}
>   Therefore the generating function
>   \begin{align*}
> P^{(\leq l, \{1,\ldots,k\})}(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}p(l,k,n)z^n\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   is a polynomial in $z$ of degree $kl$.

Introducing the short-hand notation $(z)_p=(1-z)(1-z^2)\cdots (1-z^p)$, we  want to show for $k,l\geq 0$
\begin{align*}
P^{(\leq l, \{1,\ldots,k\})}(z)=\frac{(z)_{l+k}}{(z)_l(z)_k}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> **Recurrence relation for $p(l,k,n)$:**
>
> We observe $$p(l,k,n)-p(l,k-1,n)$$
>   enumerates the number of partitions of $n$ into *exactly* $k$ parts, each $\leq l$. We transform each of these partitions by deleting every $1$ that is a part, and subtracting $1$ from each part larger than $1$. The resulting partitions of $n-k$ have at most $k$ parts and each part is $\leq l-1$.
>
> Since this transformation is reversible, it establishes a bjiection between the partitions enumerated by $p(l,k,n)-p(l,k-1,n)$ and those enumerated by $p(l-1,k,n-k)$. Therefore
>   \begin{align*}
> p(l,k,n)-p(l,k-1,n)=p(l-1,k,n-k)\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>   Thus (3) corresponds with respect to the generating function in (1) to
>   \begin{align*}
> P^{(\leq l, \{1,\ldots,k\})}(z)-P^{(\leq l, \{1,\ldots,k-1\})}(z)=z^kP^{(\leq l-1, \{1,\ldots,k\})}(z)\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>
> We have the boundary conditions
>   \begin{align*}
> p(l,0,n)=p(0,k,n)=
> \begin{cases}
> 1&\qquad \text{ if } k=l=n=0\\
> 0&\qquad \text{ otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>   since the empty partition of $0$ is the only partition in which no part is positive and is also the only partition in which the number of parts is nonpositive.
>
> This corresponds with respect to (1) to
>   \begin{align*}
> P^{(\leq l, \{0\})}(z)=P^{(0, \{1,\ldots,k\})}(z)=1
> \end{align*}

We want to show that the right hand side of (2) fulfils the same recurrence relation as (4). We introduce the short-hand notation $Q^{(l,k)}(z)$ and define
\begin{align*}
Q^{(l,k)}(z):=\frac{(z)_{l+k}}{(z)_l(z)_k}
\end{align*}

> **Recurrence relation for $Q^{(l,k)}(z)$:**
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> Q^{(l,k)}(z)-Q^{(l,k-1)}(z)&=\frac{(z)_{l+k}}{(z)_l(z)_k}-\frac{(z)_{l+k-1}}{(z)_l(z)_{k-1}}\\
> &=\frac{(z)_{l+k-1}}{(z)_l(z)_k}\left[\left(1-z^{l+k}\right)-\left(1-z^k\right)\right]\\
> &=\frac{(z)_{l+k-1}}{(z)_l(z)_k}z^k\left(1-z^l\right)\\
> &=z^k\frac{(z)_{l+k-1}}{(z)_{l-1}(z)_k}\\
> &=z^kQ^{(l-1,k)}(z)
> \end{align*}
>
> We also have
>   \begin{align*}
> Q^{(l,0)}(z)=Q^{(0,k)}(z)=1
> \end{align*}
>
> **Conclusion:** Since $Q^{(l,k)}(z)$ and $P^{(\leq l, \{1,\ldots,k\})}(z)$ satisfy the same initial conditions and the same defining recurrence they are identical and the claim follows.

**Note:** This answer is more or less verbatim **Theorem 3.1** of *[The Theory of Partitions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052163766X)* by G.E. Andrews.

Comment: Verified one time,will check some more. (+1), good work. I hope it gets more votes, it certainly deserves them.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Thanks a lot, Marko. OPs question was a good opportunity to repeat this theorem.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much

Comment: @MauricioIrace: You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 0):

These are the partitions whose Ferrers diagrams fit into a $k$-by-$l$
rectangle. Their generating functions are the
[Gaussian binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient) or "$q$-binomial coefficients"
as given by your formula.

Comment: Thank you! my question is more related on "how to understand the formula" than in the formula itself.