# Number of partitions of an integer into four parts

Tags: combinatorics

I'm interested in the following question: find the number of partitions of an integer (for example, 1000) into 4 parts not exceeding given bound (for example, 511). How to approach this? If there was no restrictions for parts, the answer would be 
$C_{1003}^3$, but I don't know how to take into account those restrictions. Any suggestions?

**Edit**: parts don't have to be distinct.

Comment: Thanks, but in that question they require parts to be distinct, I don't have such a restriction.

Comment: This is also covered here at MSE; you can use [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2237261/partitions-with-at-most-k-parts-each-of-at-most-l) for at most $3$ and $4$ parts, and then substract.

Comment: It's still not clear to me how to use recurrence relation for $p(l,k,n)$ to calculate $p(511,4,1000)$. Can anyone help?

Comment: Also, I think for this particular case must be simpler approach.